# why does the console has space when it prints python

Tags: python

I just noticed something weird

In python, if I do this

```
>>> k = 1
>>> j = 2
>>> print k,",",j
1 , 2   # prints this
```

I expected that it would be:

```
1,2
```

Why is there a space between these two, whereas

```
>>> print str(k) + "," + str(j) 
1,2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example passes the 3 arguments to `print` directly, which then converts them to strings and concatenates them together, separated by spaces.  The second example first converts and concatenates the string, then passes the entire string to `print` as a single argument.  If you were to do `print str(k), ",", str(j)` instead, you'd get the same result as the first example.

Think of `print` in terms of how functions work rather than as a keyword.  As an example, take:

```
def foo(*args):
    return ' '.join(map(str, args))
```

`foo('a', 'b', 'c')` will pass foo 3 arguments, and then return those 3 arguments joined by spaces, `'a b c'`.  `foo('a' + 'b' + 'c')` will first create the string `'abc'`, then pass that as a single argument to foo, resulting in foo returning just `'abc'`.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way `print` works in Python 2.  In Python 3, print is [more configurable](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#print).

A better way to accomplish what you want is to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print '{0},{1}'.format(k, j)
```

Or use the older style string formatting:

```
print '%d,%d' % (k, j)
```

Comment: This is really more a question about functions that accept variable length argument lists than it is about string formatting.

Answer (score 2):

That's just how it is.  One reason is probably for debugging.  Like most of the people in the rest of the world, I often use `print` statements to debug as it's quicker and easier than using `pdb` for short simple scripts.

Consider:

```
a = 1
b = 2
print a,b
```

Now this prints `1 2` which makes it pretty clear that it matches with a line where `print` got 2 arguments.  (In your examples, you pass 3 arguments to `print` the first time and only 1 the second time).  Imagine how confusing it would be if it `print a,b` gave you `12`!  You'd be looking all over your code trying to figure out where a `12` came from.  Of course, as others have noted, one work-around is to use string formatting if you have more strict requirements about how you want things to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the primary reason is likely for debugging. On that note, look what happens when you print out multiple values on the same line for debugging:

```
>>> print myObj1, myObj2
myFirstObj mySecondObj
```

This way, I don't have to print a space between variables that I'm printing out for debugging purposes, making `print` lightweight for this usage.

Of course, as others have pointed out, you're better off using `','.join(myListOfStrings)` to print comma separated list of strings